# How Can I Make My Dynamic Table Row Disappear After CheckBox is Clicked?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a Javascript function that I've been working on that checks to see if a checkbox has been checked, and then is supposed to make the row disappear that the checkbox is part of. The function so far will get the count of rows, but it won't check to see if the box is checked or not. I've included the function below, and a sample version of how the table is setup.

This is the prototype of the function.

```
  function deleteRows(){
     var objTable = document.getElementById('breakTable');
    var iRows = document.getElementById('breakTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var rowCount = iRows.length;
    alert(iRows);

        if (rowCount > 1) {
        alert("in if");
         for (var i = 0; i < objTable.rows.length; i++) {
        alert("in for");
        var chk = objTable.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0];
        alert(chk);
        if (chk.checked) {
        alert("checked");
            objTable.deleteRow(i);
            iRow--;
            i--;
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }

        }
        }
```

This is how the table/rows are configured.

```
   <wb:define id='rowNumId'>#0#</wb:define>
        <wb:hiddenInput name='rowNumId' />
        <table id="dtContainer"> <tr class="dtSection" cellspacing="0">
            <td><table id="breakTable" class="thisTable" cellspacing="0"><tr>
            <td><table id="breakRw" name="breakTable"class="inlineSelect" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 15px;">
                    <% 
                    for(int i = 0; i < breakList.size(); i++) {
                    %>
                        <tr id='row_<%=i%>' style='display: all'>
                        <td><span id="Delete_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="MSJSP_70">Delete</wb:localize></strong><span><br /> 
                        <input type="checkbox" id='BREAKREC' name='<%="BREAK_REC_" + i%>' value='<%="BREAKREC_" + i%>' />&nbsp; </td>

<td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_N" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="gaMS71">Break or Holiday</wb:localize></strong><span><br /> 
                        <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_N" submitName='<%="BREAK_N_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getBreakName() %></wb:controlField><span></td>
    
                        <td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_SD_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="g2">Start Date</wb:localize></strong><span><br /> 
                        <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_SD" submitName='<%="BREAK_SD_"+ i%>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getStartDate() %></wb:controlField><span>
                        
                        <td><span id="BREAK_ED_TEST" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="ga73">End Date</wb:localize></strong><span><br /> 
                        <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_ED" submitName='<%="BREAK_ED_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getEndDate() %></wb:controlField><span></td>
                    
                        </tr>
```

Comment: onclick of some button are you checking checkboxes checked ? How does `deleteRows()` gets called ?

Comment: I have a jQuery function that already existed (this is for work), that is called when the submit button for the page is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table structure is too complicated but here is working solution .In below code i have first find out `inputs(checkbox)` in every row inside different table then use a loop to iterate through it and check if the checkbox is check or not depending on that i have use `remove()` to remove entire `tr` which contain that checkbox.After that i have check if the `table(breakRw)` is empty if yes then i have removed the whole table.

**Demo Code** :

```js
function deleteRows() {
  var objTable = document.getElementById('breakTable');
  var iRows = document.getElementById('breakTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var rowCount = iRows.length;
  var row;
  var chk;
  if (rowCount > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objTable.rows.length; i++) {
      row = objTable.rows[i];
      //getting table->tr->td->(inputs checkbox)
      chk = row.cells[0].children[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
      //looping through trs->checkboxes
      for (var j = 0; j < chk.length; j++) {
        //if checked
        if (chk[j].checked) {
          console.log("checked");
          //remove 
          chk[j].parentNode.parentNode.remove()
          rowCount--;
          i--;

        }
      }
    }
  }
  //looping thorugh rows
  for (var i = 0; i < objTable.rows.length; i++) {
    //getting tr
    var tbl = objTable.rows[i].cells[0].children[0];
    //chcking length
    if (tbl.rows.length == 0) {
      console.log("removed table whole")
      //if table not there inside tr -> remove tr
      objTable.rows[i].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="dtContainer">
  <tr class="dtSection" cellspacing="0">
    <td>
      <table id="breakTable" class="thisTable" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table id="breakRw" name="breakTable" class="inlineSelect" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="padding: 15px;">
              <tr id='row_1' style='display: all'>
                <td>
                  <span id="Delete_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel">
             <strong>
                <wb:localize id="MSJSP_70">Delete1</wb:localize>
             </strong>
             </span><br /> <input type="checkbox" id='BREAKREC' name="BREAK_REC_1" value="BREAKREC_1" />&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_N" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="gaMS71">Break or Holiday</wb:localize></strong><span><br /> 
                        <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_N" submitName='<%="BREAK_N_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getBreakName() %></wb:controlField><span></td>
    
                        <td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_SD_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="g2">Start Date</wb:localize></strong></span><br />
                  <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_SD" submitName='<%="BREAK_SD_"+ i%>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getStartDate() %></wb:controlField></span></td>

                <td><span id="BREAK_ED_TEST" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="ga73">End Date</wb:localize></strong></span><br />
                  <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_ED" submitName='<%="BREAK_ED_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getEndDate() %></wb:controlField></span></td>

              </tr>
              <tr id='row_1' style='display: all'>
                <td>
                  <span id="Delete_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel">
             <strong>
                <wb:localize id="MSJSP_70">Delete2</wb:localize>
             </strong>
             </span><br /> <input type="checkbox" id='BREAKREC' name="BREAK_REC_1" value="BREAKREC_1" />&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_N" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="gaMS71">Break or Holiday</wb:localize></strong><span><br /> 
                        <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_N" submitName='<%="BREAK_N_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getBreakName() %></wb:controlField><span></td>
    
                        <td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_SD_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="g2">Start Date</wb:localize></strong></span><br />
                  <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_SD" submitName='<%="BREAK_SD_"+ i%>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getStartDate() %></wb:controlField></span></td>

                <td><span id="BREAK_ED_TEST" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="ga73">End Date</wb:localize></strong></span><br />
                  <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_ED" submitName='<%="BREAK_ED_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getEndDate() %></wb:controlField></span></td>
              </tr>


            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <table id="breakRw" name="breakTable" class="inlineSelect" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="padding: 15px;">

              <tr id='row_2' style='display: all'>
                <td>
                  <span id="Delete_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel">
             <strong>
                <wb:localize id="MSJSP_70">Delete3</wb:localize>
             </strong>
             </span><br />
                  <input type="checkbox" id='BREAKREC' name="BREAK_REC_2" value="BREAKREC_2" />&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_N" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="gaMS71">Break or Holiday</wb:localize></strong><span><br /> 
                        <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_N" submitName='<%="BREAK_N_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getBreakName() %></wb:controlField><span></td>
    
                        <td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_SD_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="g2">Start Date</wb:localize></strong></span><br />
                  <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_SD" submitName='<%="BREAK_SD_"+ i%>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getStartDate() %></wb:controlField></span></td>

                <td><span id="BREAK_ED_TEST" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="ga73">End Date</wb:localize></strong></span><br />
                  <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_ED" submitName='<%="BREAK_ED_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getEndDate() %></wb:controlField></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='row_1' style='display: all'>
                <td>
                  <span id="Delete_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel">
             <strong>
                <wb:localize id="MSJSP_70">Delete5</wb:localize>
             </strong>
             </span><br /> <input type="checkbox" id='BREAKREC' name="BREAK_REC_1" value="BREAKREC_1" />&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_N" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="gaMS71">Break or Holiday</wb:localize></strong><span><br /> 
                        <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_N" submitName='<%="BREAK_N_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getBreakName() %></wb:controlField><span></td>
    
                        <td style="padding-left: 12px;"><span id="BREAK_SD_TEXT" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="g2">Start Date</wb:localize></strong></span><br />
                  <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_SD" submitName='<%="BREAK_SD_"+ i%>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getStartDate() %></wb:controlField></span></td>

                <td><span id="BREAK_ED_TEST" class="dateSelectFieldLabel"><strong><wb:localize id="ga73">End Date</wb:localize></strong></span><br />
                  <span class="dateSelectFieldInput"><wb:controlField id="BREAK_ED" submitName='<%="BREAK_ED_"+ i %>' overrideId="##"><%=breaks.get(i).getEndDate() %></wb:controlField></span></td>
              </tr>

            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="deleteRows();">Delete</button>
```

Comment: This works, but it only deletes the checkbox, if I want to delete the entire row what would you reommend?

Comment: Did you check closely it's deleting entire row inside your `breakRw` ? You need this only or something else?

Comment: I put this method into my code, and updated it to reflect what I needed , but the checkbox just deletes and leaves the rest of the row.

Comment: Does your table structure is same as I have created in demo code ..? If not ..please can you show your html generated code for table .

Comment: It's at the bottom of the original.

Comment: Did you change anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217398/discussion-between-swati-and-jack-parker).

Comment: For some odd reason it's still just deleting the checkbox in my version, so the first column. I'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: This fixed it, but it looks dumb.

Any suggestions?
chk[j].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove()

Comment: Yes you can  simply write `chk[j].closest('tr').remove()`